# Where do I need to catch IO exception from? Minecraft plugin

Tags: java, exception

My compiler is yelling at me because of this function:

```
public static void writeKills() {
        
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("plugins/core/killstats.db"));
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);

        sKillStats.keySet().forEach(user -> o.writeObject(sKillStats.get(user)));
    }
```

ERROR:

````
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lyser/git/RVAS-Core/rvas-core_v0.1.1/src/main/java/core/backend/PlayerMeta.java:[325,66] unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lyser/git/RVAS-Core/rvas-core_v0.1.1/src/main/java/core/backend/PlayerMeta.java:[322,38] unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lyser/git/RVAS-Core/rvas-core_v0.1.1/src/main/java/core/backend/PlayerMeta.java:[323,32] unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown```
````

I tried throwing and catching the exception like this to no avail:

```
public static void writeKills() throws IOException {
        
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("plugins/core/killstats.db"));
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);

        try {
            sKillStats.keySet().forEach(user -> o.writeObject(sKillStats.get(user)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Try-catching the entire method produces the same error.
I have no idea where to catch please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sKillStats.keySet().forEach(user -> o.writeObject(sKillStats.get(user)));
```

`o.writeObject` throws `IOException`, a checked exception. You need to handle that exception inside the `forEach` `Consumer`, because `Consumer`s can't throw checked exceptions.

Either catch it inside the `forEach`:

```
.forEach(user -> {
  try {
    o.writeObject(sKillStats.get(user));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new UncheckedIOException(e); // Or whatever.
  }
})
```

or, better, write it as an enhanced for loop:

```
for (var user : sKillStats.keySet()) {
  o.writeObject(sKillStats.get(user));
}
```

and then the `IOException` is handled by the `throws IOException` on the method.

Note that you can also just iterate the `values()` of the map, rather than iterating the keys and getting the value:

```
for (var value : sKillStats.values()) {
  o.writeObject(value);
}
```

Note as well that you need to close your streams. The easiest way to do this is with try-with-resources:

```
try (FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("plugins/core/killstats.db"));
     ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: On a similar note... new FileOutputStream(..) throws  FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @cwittah that is a subclass of IOException, so doesn't need to be handled separately.